# How to handle large CSV in camel DSL with bindy, using camel stand alone?

Tags: apache-camel, splitter

I am working on a case where I have to convert CSV file into another CSV with custom format where I am using bindy component and its good with annotation,

`MyRoute:`

```
final DataFormat inputCSV = new BindyCsvDataFormat(InputCSV.class);
final DataFormat outputCSV = new BindyCsvDataFormat(OutputCSV.class); 

from("file:inbox/inputFile?fileName=inputProducts.csv&noop=true")
                .split().tokenize("\n", 500)
                .unmarshal(inputCSV)
                .bean(Processor.class, "processCSV")
                .marshal(outputCSV)
                .to("file:inbox/outputFile?fileExist=append&fileName=outProduct.csv");
        }
```

Here I'm getting different output every time

`Input CSV file contain 3000 row`

1) its keep repeating data again and again its produce 7000+ row

2)If I do chunk size 800 its work as 21row,100row and random row with repeating row.

3)If I do 1000 chunk size its not working, nothing is hpn.

4)I don't know how it is work `Thread.sleep(5000) more time more repeating row`.

5)And after every chunks its generate header which is I want to generate once.

I also try with threads() and streaming().

My question is why split chunks not working as it has to and why its reading data again and again?

Comment: You are sure the file is delimited by line feed and not control line feed?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. @SoucianceEqdamRashti

Comment: The only way this will not work is if the token character does not match correcly to your file.

Comment: It's simple CSV file with 3000 row and every line is separate one by one, I don't know what to do

Comment: Yhh it's working I have to put like this **"\\n"**